# R row.names and colnames: inconsistent?

Tags: r, syntax

I have a dataframe, for example:

```
MyUSArrests <- USArrests
```

To retrieve row names, I would use the function `row.names` or `rownames`.

To retrieve column names, I would use the function `colnames`, without the full point in the latter. There is no `col.names` function.

I find it inconsistent. I would expect `col.names` to exist.

Comment: In which function?

Comment: @user2974951 you mean which package? these are R standard functions

Comment: `row.names` is for `data.frames`.

Comment: and there exists also a `rownames` like `colnames`.

Comment: @GKi but there is `row.names` but no `col.names`

Comment: From the documentation, `row.names is similar to rownames for arrays, and it has a method that calls rownames for an array argument.`

Comment: @robertspierre you point out something, you can read a lot about. The flexibility of R and its package system comes at the price of many implementations and - possibly - differing naming regimes ... and the inconsistencies you flag. You can always define a function for yourself, e.g. col.names <- function(x){return(colnames(x))} to ease the pain and establish the consistency you are looking for.